# Detect river when moving troops?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

Is there any good indication to see when you are crossing rivers or is this only shown visually on the map itself?

Take London and Bedfort for example, is there a river in between those counties? There is on starting in the middle of Bedfort but it lies behind it's city. If there is no river then would there be a river between Northhampton and Bedfort? I cannot find a UI indication about this, that would be very handy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you select any province which has a water crossing, a small water crossing icon will be on the right side of the middle "ribbon" (under the province capitol icon).  Hovering over the icon will give you a list of all provinces that have a water crossing with that province, in addition to the type of crossing (river, strait, etc).  I don't know of any other way to check if two specific provinces have water crossings between them, you just have to select either the province you are moving from or moving to and check if the other one shows up on the list.